# Typeahead suggestions with key down and keyup, scrollbar is not moving

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have used scrollbar for typeahead suggestions. but when i move keydown the item scrollbar is not moving and selected item is not showing up.

Here is the js

```
$("input").typeahead({
source: ["Alpha", "Alphabet", "Alfa", "Armadillo","ksdjflksdjfl","jksdjflsdjl","qi2ueouqwoei","jalhflasdf","pwoipa","ahweurw","qwipoqwieo"]
});
```

Here is the Css:

```
.typeahead.dropdown-menu {
 z-index: 100001;
 }

  .modal-body {
     overflow-y: visible
   }
  .typeahead {
    max-height: 100px !important;
    overflow-y: auto  !important;
    overflow-x: hidden  !important;
    padding-right: 20px  !important;
   }
```

Here is the html:

```
<div class='modal'>
<div class='modal-body'>
    Hello
    <input />
</div>
<div class='modal-footer'>
    <button class='btn' data-toggle='modal'>Toggle</button>
</div>
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KAVx7/5/

How to solve this issue.

Comment: does typeahead support this feature ? because if not, you will have to write seperate code for this. This feature was also not present in jquery tokeninput and someone had written a custom code for it

Comment: @MandeepJain: I didn't find any documentation regarding typeahead supporting scrollbar. Can you please provide me the link for custom code written for jquery tokeninput.

Comment: https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/issues/130  look for  psiphiorg's solution from the bottom. But I am afraid its integrated into the plugin, so you wont be able to use it directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading the latest version 0.9.3 fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/7418) discussed you problem take a look and try solution from rsteier comment.

Comment: Actually on clicking scrollbar menu is hidden in the link you have provided. I have already gone through the link and tried to use the solution but on no use. But in my case menu is not hidden when scrollbar is or moved. In my case when moving down the selected item scrollbar is not moving so the selected item at the end of suggestions is not showing up.